# toggle div keep as it is after page refresh or change

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this example. I need my div is open if page is change or refresh.
I have given my HTML and Javascript.

This is where my code is live http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/fauNg/1/

```
    $(".widget2").hide();
    $(".box2").toggle(function() {
        $(this).next(".widget2").slideDown(200);
    }, function() {
        $(this).next(".widget2").slideUp(200);
    });

    $(".inner").hide();
    $(".box").toggle(function() {
        $(this).next(".inner").slideDown(200);
    }, function() {
        $(this).next(".inner").slideUp(200);
    });?

<div class="box2"><h3>Basketball</h3>
</div>
<div class="widget2" style="display: block; "><div class="widget"><div class="box"><h3>Australia</h3></div>
        <div class="inner" style="display: block; ">
            <ul class="leagues">
                                    <li class="even"><a href="/baloncesto/australian-nbl/" class="league-145">Australian NBL</a></li>
                            </ul>
            <div class="clear-both"></div>
        </div></div>
</div>?
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [javascript coockie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) to save the `Open` and `close` state for each menu, and read the state when page loads. this is the only way to go since every time page is refreshed, everything is reset.

Comment: Can you show me how I use cookie in this [Program](http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/fauNg/1/)

Comment: this is how it works, http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/s6RzW/, you should optimize the code yourself, what I do there is only for demo of persistent state.

Comment: the link was not right. here is the right link: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/s6RzW/1/

Comment: no dear I made that before I post my question. this is it http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/fauNg/1/

Comment: @user599806, I am saying, please click this link: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/s6RzW/1/,, it shows you how to use cookies to keep state.

Comment: Thanks for that but it's not working when I click on any link of last state.. all menu is expand. and after toggle need double click to open and close. check here.. http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/s6RzW/2/ in this when you reload the page all states are open after reload

Answer (score 0):

When you make a change, you can change what's after the # at the end of the url. Then when the page is reloaded, you read the value after the hash in `$(document).ready()` and make the changes accordingly.

Comment: I create this example over here.[my program](http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/fauNg/1/) I don't think that will work for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **is** function to check if your div is hidden and show it

```
if($(".selector").is(":hidden"))
   $(".selector").show();
```

Furthermore as @mikel said, put it inside document ready function for checking on pageload.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      if($(".selector").is(":hidden"))
       $(".selector").show();
});
```